# How to build two version of .net framework at one click on visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build

below is what I want:

There are several versions of .Net Framework, like 3.5 and 4.0. Is there a way on Visual Studio to click the build button and get two built .exe or .dll files?
I know there is "Batch Build" in Visual Studio to build several .exe at the same time, but I can create different build configurations. But I cannot assign different build configuration with different .Net Framework version and get the build result at the same time. Did I miss something or is there any work around?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: vote up or down answers and mark as best answer if any of them be useful

Comment: The IDE does not support different framework targets for different configurations.  It is a project setting, not a configuration setting.

Comment: @Hans Passant Then is it possible to ran one msbuild command to get two version of .net framework built result?

Comment: @Hans: accept answer if it was useful.

Answer (score 1):

To do this you should have one Major project that develop on one it. its version is 3.5

create another project and add first project files to it. after build the solution you have two version of compilation from your code.

to have a clean work you can use Post-Build event to copy output files to another directory.

ask me if any point is not clear